# Remove suffix from column name

Tags: mysql, sql

Some of my columns have the suffix `_a` at the end.
I want to check, if the column has such a suffix and if so, just remove it from my result set.

This is my query:

```
SELECT t1.column_name FROM information_schema.Columns t1
WHERE t1.table_name = 'myTab1' AND t1.table_schema = 'myDatabase1'
```

I need to add something like:

```
IF(SUBSTR(column_name, -2) == "_a", SUBSTR("column_name", 0, -2))
```

So that `col_a` becomes `col`.

I need to keep the suffix, so I can't just rename my column names completely.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? I do not understand your question: first you say: _if the column has such a suffix and if so, just remove it._ at the end of your post say: _so I can't just rename my column names_

Comment: @lolka_bolka: I want to remove the suffix in my result set, but I don't want to rename the columns.

Comment: You want to remove the suffix within your code, but keep it on the database side?  If i'm understanding this correctly, this is exactly what aliases are used for (i.e. `select t1.column_name_a as column_name`)

Comment: You can try describe table name like talbe name = abc;   DESCRIBE abc;You can see the all coloum names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\` is to escape the special character `_`.

```
SELECT case when t1.column_name like '%\_a' then SUBSTRING(t1.column_name, 1, length(t1.column_name)-2)
            when t1.column_name like '%|a' then SUBSTRING(t1.column_name, 1, length(t1.column_name)-2)  
       else t1.column_name end
FROM information_schema.Columns t1
WHERE t1.table_name = 'myTab1' AND t1.table_schema = 'myDatabase1'
```

Based on the comment, if the string pattern being searched for should contain `|a` use `t1.column_name like '%|a'`

[Sample fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c5a68a/9)

Comment: Thank you. What about if I have another suffix, like `|a`? Simply changing `_` by `|` didn't work.

Comment: You don't need the \ in that case. The \ was to escape the special character `_` which means "any 1 character"

Comment: @user1170330.. `\\`  is to escape special character `_`. | isn't a special character. so you can use `like `|a` in that case.

Comment: check the edited version. it had to be `substring` instead of `substr`.

Comment: I suggest explicitely tagging the escape character: `LIKE '%\_a' ESCAPE '\'`

Answer (score -1):

Slightly less dynamic (but arguably more readable) solution would be something like this:

```
 Select t1.column_name_a as column_name, t1.column_name2_a as t1.column_name2
 from information_schema.Columns t1
 where t1.table_name = 'myTab1' and t1.table_schema = 'myDatabase1'
```

If you truly need something dynamic, use one of the other proposed answers.  If your column names are going to be consistent, this is probably the more standard practice from what I've personally seen.